# Mapping large data into list in Dart/Flutter Asynchronously

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a big list of data represented in a JSON-like object. It's an `Iterable<Map<String, dynamic>>` acquired from an SQLite database.

Running the query and even filtering the resulting data runs asynchronously, but when I try to map this data into a class, the Main Thread freezes.

The whole block of code is in an async function, and it returns a future of data, but for some reason, `toList` only runs synchronously.

I tried to use `compute`, but it keeps saying

`Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message : (object is a closure - Function '<anonymous closure>':.)`

I even tried RxDart's `asyncMap`, but that didn't seem to work any differently.

Trying to avoid `function` and use a normal `for` didn't work either.

What can I do to get the mapping code to run asynchronously?

This is the exact code that has the issue

```dart
    final filteredCards = cardsRaw.where((e) {
      return csvData.any(
        (element) =>
            e['card_name'] == element.cardName &&
            (e['number'] as String).startsWith(element.cardNumber) &&
            e['set_name'] == element.setName,
      );
    }).toList();
```

`cardsRaw` is 11k, and `csvData` is 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart is single threaded, this means that even an async call will freeze the main thread if it has an expensive calculation.

The correct way of doing it is to spawn an isolate using `compute` like you tried, but `compute` can only take **top-level** (functions declared outside of a class) or **static** functions, that's the reason for your error.

Flutter has a handy [cookbook](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/background-parsing) that explains how to parse JSON in the background:

> You can remove the jank by moving the parsing and conversion to a background isolate using the compute() function provided by Flutter. The compute() function runs expensive functions in a background isolate and returns the result.

Comment: I tried that, but compute only knows a few types of data. `Iterable` is not one of them, so that doesn't solve my issue

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: [This example](https://i.imgur.com/MQH1DXF.png) uses `compute` with an `Iterable` and also returns a `Map`, which should be what you want.

Comment: I eventually ported much of the blocking code to compute, but wasn't easy or convenient